# Search for not merged pull requests in GitHub

Tags: github

I want search for not merged pull requests.
I tried in GitHub:

Doesn't work:

```
-merged 
!is:merged
is not:merged
not is:merged
```

find merged works:

`is:merged`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the proper search is

```
is:pr is:unmerged
```

https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests